# I am trying to update React Native from 0.63.5 to 0.64.0.Everything works fine in debug config Xcode but changing to release results in white screen

Tags: xcode, react-native

```
"dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^4.10.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.9",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.10",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.6.9",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "8.3.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "8.4.12",
    "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^12.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.6.2",
    "appcenter": "4.0.2",
    "appcenter-analytics": "4.0.2",
    "appcenter-crashes": "4.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "clevertap-react-native": "^0.5.0",
    "clone-deep": "^4.0.1",
    "d3-shape": "^1.3.5",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "lottie-react-native": "^3.5.0",
    "mitt": "^2.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "opentok-react-native": "^0.18.0",
    "paths-js": "^0.4.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.1",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-check-app-install": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.4",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-drax": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-elevated-view": "0.0.6",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-iap": "^7.5.6",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.35.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-immersive": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-in-app-review": "^3.2.2",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-mime-types": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-moengage": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-motion": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-navbar-color": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.9",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-public-ip": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-reconnecting-websocket": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.2.4",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.17",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-share": "^7.6.1",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-speedometer": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-speedometer-chart": "^0.7.5",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-text-ticker": "^1.10.0",
    "react-native-timer": "^1.3.6",
    "react-native-translucent-modal": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-tts": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-typewriter": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-typing-animation": "^0.1.7",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.0-alpha8",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.9.3",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-persist": "^4.9.1",
    "redux-persist-transform-immutable": "^4.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "validator": "^13.1.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "appcenter-crashes": "^4.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "easy-peasy": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "prettier-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16"
  },
```

Here is my package.json

Xcode version - 14.2
Node version - 16.15.1

I have tried multiple solutions from upgrading xcode to latest version and trying different scripts in Build phases -> Bundle React native code and images.I have also followed step by step guide from
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.5&to=0.64.1

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: No error messages in console a few warning logs related to firebase and Fbsdk